# Accessing data from different methods?

Tags: java, methods

I'm really new to programming so sorry if i'm missing something completely easy. Have been stuck on this issue for the past few days.

I've made a method which reads a files text. (readText) The text file has multiple lines. Each line has a user with multiple scores. The name and scores each have their own variable assigned to them. This is repeated per line. I know the file is getting read as if I do a println in the same method, it outputs all scores corresponding to that but per line(another problem I will solve later I hope)

In another method(totalScore), I'm trying to access the names and scores and use them for some adding/subtracting etc.

For the life of me, I just can't access the variables from the readText method in totalScore.

Code:

```
    public static boolean readText() {
    File file = new File("C:/test.txt");

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");

            int id = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
            String firstName = words[1];
            String lastName = words[2];
            int score1 = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
            int score2 = Integer.parseInt(words[4]);
            int score3 = Integer.parseInt(words[5]);
            int score4 = Integer.parseInt(words[6]);

            addUser(id, firstName, lastName, score1, score2, score3,score4);

        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to read file");
    }
    return true;
}

private static void addUser(id,firstName,lastName,score1,score2,score3,score4); {
}

private static void totalScore() {

totalsc = score1+score2;
}
```

Comment: you should either pass them as arguments (same as you do in `addUser`) or else make those variables *global*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do like under:

```
public static boolean readText() {
    File file = new File("C:/test.txt");

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");

            int id = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
            String firstName = words[1];
            String lastName = words[2];
            int score1 = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
            int score2 = Integer.parseInt(words[4]);
            int score3 = Integer.parseInt(words[5]);
            int score4 = Integer.parseInt(words[6]);

            addUser(id, firstName, lastName, score1, score2, score3,score4);

        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to read file");
    }
    return true;
}

private static void addUser(int id, String firstName,String  lastName, int score1,int score2,int score3,int score4) {
    return;
}

private static void totalScore(int score1, int score2) {
    int totalsc = 0;
    totalsc = score1+score2;
}
```